# Process on kill event C#

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm using C# WPF.
I have list of Process that i run them with `Start()` command.

I want to know when the user exit from the process and to catch the event.
What i'm tried:

```
myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = fileName;
myProcess.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
myProcess.Exited += new EventHandler(myProcess_Exited);
myProcess.Start();
```

*myProcess is Process object.

The problem is immediately after `Start()` command the application is closed and `myProcess_Exited` callback called.
Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The only reason for that behaviour is, that the exe you start is closing or crahsing directly after starting it. For example if the exe is a `console` application which does not have any user-input or some thing else. Try your code with `Notepad.exe` and you'll see it works.

Take a look at this `IronPython` code, which is mainly .net code as your application (only easier for testing purpose):

from System.Diagnostics import Process

```
def on_exit(s, e):
    print ('Exited')

process = Process()
process.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\\Windows\\System32\\notepad.exe"
process.EnableRaisingEvents = True
process.Exited += on_exit;
process.Start()
```

Exit is called if i close Notepad.

**EDIT**

If you want to detected which app was closed/exited, just case your `sender` object to `Process` and access it's `FileName` over `StartInfo`. For example:

```
private void OnExited(object sender, EventArgs, e)
{
    var process = (sender as Process);
    Console.WriteLine(process.StartInfo.FileName);
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, i'm trying again with notepad like you say. the application is really not immediately closed but when i'm close the process the callback isnt called

Comment: update: now its work :) thank you!..how can i know the application name that closed inside the callback?

Comment: @MikeBrown I added an example for you.

Answer (score -1):

```
myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = fileName;
myProcess.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
myProcess.Exited += new EventHandler(myProcess_Exited);
myProcess.Start();
myProcess.WaitForExit();
```

Or,

```
myProcess.WaitForExit(timeout);
```

Comment: I think he will start a list of processes in the same Thread, than `WaitForExit` is not usable.

Comment: thanks. how can i know the application name that closed inside the callback?

Comment: I think the other part of your problem is the command line application. Launch notepad with your code and it should all work. If that works then you can trouble shoot the command line applicaiton. In the exit even you can cast the object sender back to a process.
            Process p = sender as Process;